# Azure webjobs suddenly stopped working

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, webjob, azure-webjobs-triggered

From one day to the other, my manually triggered Azure webjobs does not work anymore. I am trying to trigger them using the "Run" button in the Azure portal.

My WebJob does not do anything "fancy", they just read from an Azure blob queue, do some processing and uploads a csv file afterwards.

The error message I am seeing in the Azure portal is:

```
"Failed to run [JOBNAME].: "No route registered for '/api/triggeredwebjobs/[JOBNAME]/history?api-version=2016-03-01'"
```

If I check the browser console I can see an http 404 error, when a http POST is being made to the following endpoint:

https://web1.appsvcux.ext.azure.com/websites/api/Websites/RunWebJob

If I click that link, I am shown an 401.1 error page with the following text:

```
Access is denied.

Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. This may have been caused by an incorrect user name and/or password.
```

Error message 401.1: Logon credentials were not recognized. Make sure you are providing the correct user name and password. Otherwise, contact the Web server's administrator for help.

I have not made any changes in the Azure portal or to the webjob code since long ago (> month ago).
I even tried to setup a completely new Azure webjob, but I get the same error message.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Refer to this GitHub wiki Site-level credentials:https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials#site-level-credentials-aka-publish-profile-credentials 
You may also refer to the MSDN link
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d74619f-5b16-43e0-a370-a1df5810c5f8/azure-web-jobs-just-stoped-working?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Yes, we are working on a fix. Please track MSDN thread for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by an Azure issue that caused WebJobs invocations from the worker to fail with that error.

The issue has now been resolved, and you will no longer encounter this. See [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e046ef98-ae3a-4942-819f-b62e1775b533/app-service-customers-trying-to-run-a-triggered-webjob-manually-may-see-failures-and-error-message?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) for related info.

Apologies for the inconvenience.